# loadkeys says "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console" in chroot on ChromeOS

Tags: console, chroot, chrome-os

I've been trying the "Developer console" in ChromeOS( dev mode), which is entered by Ctrl+Alt+Forward but when switching the keyboard layout with `loadkeys cz` I got an error saying `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`.

- I get the same when chroot is entered from crosh, but in that case the layout set in ChromeOS is used, which is fine.

I can see that the [keyboard code](https://askubuntu.com/a/209598/79176) is correct with `ls /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`

In addition I've found the response of `loadkeys`is the same in [Crosh](http://chrome-extension://nkoccljplnhpfnfiajclkommnmllphnl/html/crosh.html), only there is the language/layout inherited from the system setup.

Is there any other way to set the keyboard mapping/layout in shell?

Comment: Are you root? What is the output of `ls -l /dev/console` ?

Comment: @Gilles Yes.( Although I thought that wouldn't be needed.)  The listing gives a line `crw-------. 1 root root 5, 1 Feb  6 14:53 /dev/console`

Comment: `fgconsole` produces this errormessage when not run from `$TERM=linux` (tty*)
eg. xterm, konsole etc.

Comment: note `loadkeys` loads from `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps`.  you might try `setxkbmap` instead, though i wonder if that will still work under Freon.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about ChromeOS, but I get this same error with `loadkeys` and `setfont` on my Arch Linux machine when inside a `screen` session.  The fix is to use an explicit `-C` option to specify the console:

```
$ loadkeys -C /dev/console cz
```

If you don't have write access to the console, a different error will occur:

> Couldn't open /dev/console

In this case, any means of providing the correct privileges will do.  I just use `sudo` or you can change the owner:

```
sudo chown myusername:myusername /dev/console
```

---

Note that the X11 keyboard layouts are not used by `loadkeys`, which is for the text console.  Instead the files are in `/usr/share/kbd/keymaps` and have a different format.

The `cz` layout should still be available, but a customized layout for X11 would need to be ported.